Setting up Storm topology using Streamparser
I am trying to run the wordcount topology using
sparse run but I am getting the error
I have configured
storm/conf/storm.yaml as
# List of Zookeeper servers to be used by Storm. 
storm.zookeeper.servers:
    - "localhost"

# Port to connect to Zookeeper servers
storm.zookeeper.port: 2181

# List of seed hosts that nimbus will use to join the cluster.
nimbus.seeds: ["localhost"]

# The port storm nimbus daemon runs on. Default is 6627.
nimbus.thrift.port: 6627

# Directory where Storm local state is stored. Ensure this directory exists and is writable by Storm.
storm.local.dir: "/path/to/storm-local"

# Ports that supervisors will use to launch workers. Can be customized.
supervisor.slots.ports:
    - 6700
    - 6701
    - 6702
    - 6703

# Enable the web UI server on this host.
ui.port: 8080

and then started bin/storm supervisor, bin/storm nimbus and bin/storm ui but get the following error
20:29:20.614 [main] WARN  o.a.s.u.NimbusClient - Ignoring exception while trying to get leader nimbus info from localhost. will retry with a different seed host.
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
Any suggestion will be appreciated
